# Could the complex zeros of Riemann zeta function be of the form $ s=0.5+ik$ with $k$ a positive integer?

Tags: nt.number-theory, analytic-number-theory, prime-numbers, riemann-zeta-function, transcendental-number-theory

I have checked in [Andrew Odlyzko](http://www.dtc.umn.edu/~odlyZko/zeta_tables/index.html), Tables of zeros of the Riemann zeta function, to know if there is an example of zeros of Riemann zeta function with integer imaginary parts, but I don't see that. I would like to know if there is an example of zeros as $s=0.5+at$ with $a$ a positive integer .

> > **Now my question here is:**
> >
> > Could the complex zeros of the Riemann zeta function be of the form $ s=0.5+ik$  with $k$ a positive integer?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What would it change if some non-trivial zero had an integer imaginary part ?

Comment: Why would you expect that ?

Comment: May if it will with integer imaginary part i think this give different property than it's with real imaginary part , the well know of the real imaginary part the zeros had a chaotic behavior . I w'd like to know if there is any proof show to us the complex zeros could be or no  with integer imaginary part depend of structure for Riemann zeta function

Comment: It is conjectured that the nontrivial zeroes of $\zeta(s)$ are of the form $\rho = 1/2 + i\gamma$ with $\gamma$ transcendental and such that there are no linear relations over $\mathbb{Q}$ between the set of all $\gamma$. In particular, it is conjectured that there are no nontrivial zeroes of $\zeta(s)$ of the form $1/2 + ik$ with $k$ an integer. However, currently we have no way of attacking this conjecture.

Comment: @PeterHumphries, i don't know why my question is not well received

Comment: Well, the question not particularly well-written. Your note at the end is rather impenetrable: it's not clear what this has to do with twin primes in any way.

Comment: Ok, thanks for that , i edited it now and i have eliminated the twin prime topic .

Comment: @PeterHumphries, do u have any paper disscussed the conjecture that you cited  ?

Comment: The conjecture that there are no linear relations between the set of all $\gamma$ is known as the Linear Independence hypothesis (or occasionally the Grand Simplicity hypothesis). As far as I'm aware, it was first suggested in Rubinstein and Sarnak's paper "Chebyshev's Bias".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As explained by Peter Humphries in the comments, the famous conjecture here is that the imaginary part of the non-trivial zeros of $\zeta(s)$ is transcendental (or equivalently, linearly independent over $\mathbb{Q}$).

I'm not sure of the origins of the conjecture, but it was certainly around before the Rubinstein-Sarnak paper. Rumely a year before alredy says that it is "generally believed" for all Dirichlet L-functions. Both papers are avaible online:

- Robert Rumely, "[Numerical Computations Concerning the ERH](http://www.ams.org/mcom/1993-61-203/S0025-5718-1993-1195435-0/S0025-5718-1993-1195435-0.pdf)" (1993)
- Michael Rubinstein & Peter Sarnak, "[Chebyshev's bias](https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.em/1048515870)" (1994)

In particular, you can consider the fact that $k$ is not an integer as numerically verified at least in the range in which the RH has (up to $10^{13}$ after Gourdon).

Comment: Err... how can you numerically verify that a number is transcendental? Supposedly you are talking here about the conjecture that no $\gamma$ is integer, not about the one you cite. :-)

Comment: @Wolfgang You know what I meant hehe

Comment: @Myshkin, i'm not an expert or professional with zeta function or with the cited conjecture , but I think billions of zeros of Riemann zeta function have a real part equal's 0.5 and we can't even now to judg if it is true or no , then how  we can accept the conjecture which showed that's the imaginary part is not integer hold's numerically up 10 ^13 , reall i'm interesting to know if there is any mathematical basic  disproof or proof that we can have a zero with integer imaginary part !!!!"I'm confused why my question in hold"

Comment: @zeraouliarafik Hardy proved a century ago (1914) that there are infinite zeros with real part equal to 1/2 (not just "billions"). But for a fixed height the number of zeros is finite, and we have the tools to calculate them. This is basic Riemann zeta function theory, and that is why it was closed (not research level). I recommend you to have a look at Titchmarsh's or Patterson's introductory books on $\zeta(s)$, it is a beautiful subject!

Comment: @zeraouliarafik For example, Rimann himself calculated the first zero (14.13472514...), therefore proving that there are no zeros with integer part in that range (from 0 to 14.13472514...). With more powerful techniques, this has been extended to $(0,10^{13})$.